# How can you open a video on your desktop at a specific time using terminal?

Tags: terminal, video, unix

I wanted to know if it was possible to open a mp4 file located on my desktop right at a specific time of the video (e.g. 1 hour 10 minutes 30 seconds) using the terminal?

`$ open /Volumes/USERNAME/Desktop/lecture.mp4`

This works for starting at the beginning of the video.

But how could I include a specific time (hours, minutes, seconds) at where the video opens/starts at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [**VLC**](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) media player installed, you can run the following example  *compound command* in **Terminal** to start playing the video *file* at the 1 hour 10 minutes 30 seconds mark:

```
open -a /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC '/path/to/name.mp4' --args --start-time 4230
```

Showing on two lines to see the whole *compound command*:

```
open -a /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC \
    '/path/to/name.mp4' --args --start-time 4230
```

Using the default **macOS** `open` *command* to open **VLC** and pass it the `--start-time` *option*, the *value* of which is expressed in *seconds*.

`open` *options*:

- **-a application** -- Specifies the application to use for opening the file.
- **--args** -- All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to main(). These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the **open** tool.

`VLC` *option*:

- **--start-time**  -- Starts the video here; the integer is the number of seconds from the beginning (e.g. 1:30 is written as 90).

See also: [Documentation:Command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/)